# With pandas, how to speed up iteration that requires using the previous rows calculated value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here's the code in question:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        list(range(200)),
        list(range(200, 400))
    ],
    index=['col_1', 'col_2']
).transpose()

col_1_index = df.columns.get_loc('col_1')
col_2_index = df.columns.get_loc('col_2')

target_1 = 2

for i in range(2, len(df)):
    if (
        df.iloc[i - 2, col_1_index] -
        df.iloc[i - 1, col_2_index]
    ) > target_1:
        col_2_value = (
            df.iloc[i - 1, col_2_index] +
            target_1
        )
    elif (
        df.iloc[i - 1, col_2_index] -
        df.iloc[i - 2, col_1_index]
    ) > target_1:
        col_2_value = (
            df.iloc[i - 1, col_2_index] -
            target_1
        )
    else:
        col_2_value = df.iloc[i - 2, col_1_index]

    df.iloc[i, col_2_index] = col_2_value

df

'''
# expected output
  col_1 col_2
0   0    200
1   1    201
2   2    199
3   3    197
4   4    195
... ...  ...
195 195  193
196 196  194
197 197  195
198 198  196
199 199  197
'''
```

My issue is I can't use the common methods of speeding up the iteration such as `df.itertuples()` or `df.apply()` because I am referencing the previous row's calculated value.

---

The logic is iterating over the `DataFrame` comparing the `t-2` col_1 value with the `t-1` col_2 value to decide what to assign to the `t` col_2 value. So col_1 is static, while the col_2 time `t` value is updated each iteration.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example of an input and the matching expected output

Comment: Working on that now.

Comment: Just added sample input and the expected output.

Comment: Please also briefly explain the logic

Comment: `My issue is I can't use the common methods of speeding up the iteration such as df.itertuples() [...] because I am referencing the previous row's calculated value.` You definitely can. You can save the last value in a variable and reference it in the next loop.

Comment: @NickODell thanks for the recommendation. I ended up implementing what you suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well `itertuples` or `apply` are not especially fast, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/9274732). Your main problem is you access cells several times in the loop and assign value to a cell at each loop. One can be more efficient by just looping on values from col_1 and have a variable to keep the previous value calculated, `append` the result in a list (faster than assign to a specific cell) and outside of the loop, assign the column at once. Here is one way:

```
prev_val2 = df.iloc[1, col_2_index] 
l_val2 = [df.iloc[0, col_2_index], prev_val2] #for the results

for val1 in df['col_1'].to_numpy()[:-2]:
    if (val1-prev_val2)>target_1:
        prev_val2 += target_1
    elif (prev_val2-val1)>target_1:
        prev_val2 -= target_1
    else:
        prev_val2 = val1
    l_val2.append(prev_val2)

df['col_2_fast'] = l_val2 #assign outside of the loop
```

Now on a 200-row dataframe, the speed comparison goes from **61.5 ms** with your method to **0.380 ms** with this one (about 160 times faster) and the gain should increase with the size of the dataframe. And of course, after running your method and this one, `df['col_2'].eq(df['col_2_fast']).all()` gives `True`.

Comment: This is a very good approach. I don't need to actually assign the col_2 value until the very end. I already implemented @nickodell answer but I will try yours as well.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by taking @nickodell recommendation to save the previous value as a variable.

Time comparison of original code vs optimized code below:

`CPU times: total: 46.9 ms` vs. `CPU times: total: 15.6 ms`

```py
import pandas as pd

def calc(df):
    col_1_tmin2_val = df['col_1'][0]
    col_1_tmin1_val = df['col_1'][1]
    col_2_tmin1_val = df['col_2'][1]
    
    def func_apply(row: pd.Series) -> float:
        nonlocal col_1_tmin2_val
        nonlocal col_1_tmin1_val
        nonlocal col_2_tmin1_val

        if (col_1_tmin2_val - col_1_tmin1_val) > target_1:
            col_2_value = (col_2_tmin1_val + target_1)
        elif (col_2_tmin1_val - col_1_tmin2_val) > target_1:
            col_2_value = (col_2_tmin1_val - target_1)
        else:
            col_2_value = col_1_tmin2_val

        col_1_tmin2_val = col_1_tmin1_val
        col_1_tmin1_val = row['col_1']
        col_2_tmin1_val = col_2_value

        return col_2_value

    df.iloc[2:, col_2_index] = df.iloc[2:].apply(lambda x: func_apply(x), axis=1)

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        list(range(200)),
        list(range(200, 400))
    ],
    index=['col_1', 'col_2']
).transpose()

col_2_index = df.columns.get_loc('col_2')

target_1 = 2
    
calc(df)
    
df
```